# javascript: how to get all ids of a json array with for loop

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a problem getting the different ids from my json object.
I get are the id of the last item.

This is the function:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://wjko5u2865.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles"; 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   var allart = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for(let i = 0; i < allart.Items.length; i++)
    {
      document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = allart.Items[i].id;
    }
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This is the json array I get:

```js
{
  "Items":[{
    "marca":"Guzzi",
    "titolo":"Moto Guzzi V100 Mandello, la regina di EICMA 2021",
    "id":"123456",
    "immagine":"moto_guzzi_v100_mandello.jpg",
    "data":"27/11/2021"
    },
    {
    "marca":"Bimota","titolo":"Bimota: arriverà un'adventure su base Tesi",
    "id":"135623",
    "immagine":"bimota-_arrivera_unadventure_su_base_tesi.jpg",
    "data":"04/12/2021"
    },
    {
    "marca":"Ducati",
    "titolo":"Ducati, la DesertX sarà svelata a Dubai il 9 dicembre",
    "id":"123789",
    "immagine":"b_desertx-dwp2022-2-uc336332-high.jpg",
    "data":"04/12/2021"
    },
    {"marca":"Benelli",
    "titolo":"EICMA 2021, Benelli \"sforna\" le moto più attese",
    "id":"146975",
    "immagine":"benelli_2.jpg",
    "data":"27/11/2021"
    }
    ],
    "Count":4,"ScannedCount":4}
```

Thanks to all in advance

Comment: `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = ...` simply finds the DOM element with ID "id" and writes the content to that same element over and over.  That's probably not what you want to do but it's not clear what your HTML contains or what exactly you want to happen.

Comment: You're rewriting the 'id="id"' element each time. Try adding to it instead, like `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML += "<br/>" + allart.Items[i].id;`

Comment: @Kinglish Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete error in your code was this line:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = allart.Items[i].id;
```

It needs a "+" before the "=" to add more strings/ids to the innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML += "<br/>"+allart.Items[i].id;
```

I made an alternative solution where I use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of all the ids and then [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create a string with all the ids.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "data:application/json;base64,ewogICJJdGVtcyI6W3sKICAgICJtYXJjYSI6Ikd1enppIiwKICAgICJ0aXRvbG8iOiJNb3RvIEd1enppIFYxMDAgTWFuZGVsbG8sIGxhIHJlZ2luYSBkaSBFSUNNQSAyMDIxIiwKICAgICJpZCI6IjEyMzQ1NiIsCiAgICAiaW1tYWdpbmUiOiJtb3RvX2d1enppX3YxMDBfbWFuZGVsbG8uanBnIiwKICAgICJkYXRhIjoiMjcvMTEvMjAyMSIKICAgIH0sCiAgICB7CiAgICAibWFyY2EiOiJCaW1vdGEiLCJ0aXRvbG8iOiJCaW1vdGE6IGFycml2ZXLgIHVuJ2FkdmVudHVyZSBzdSBiYXNlIFRlc2kiLAogICAgImlkIjoiMTM1NjIzIiwKICAgICJpbW1hZ2luZSI6ImJpbW90YS1fYXJyaXZlcmFfdW5hZHZlbnR1cmVfc3VfYmFzZV90ZXNpLmpwZyIsCiAgICAiZGF0YSI6IjA0LzEyLzIwMjEiCiAgICB9LAogICAgewogICAgIm1hcmNhIjoiRHVjYXRpIiwKICAgICJ0aXRvbG8iOiJEdWNhdGksIGxhIERlc2VydFggc2Fy4CBzdmVsYXRhIGEgRHViYWkgaWwgOSBkaWNlbWJyZSIsCiAgICAiaWQiOiIxMjM3ODkiLAogICAgImltbWFnaW5lIjoiYl9kZXNlcnR4LWR3cDIwMjItMi11YzMzNjMzMi1oaWdoLmpwZyIsCiAgICAiZGF0YSI6IjA0LzEyLzIwMjEiCiAgICB9LAogICAgeyJtYXJjYSI6IkJlbmVsbGkiLAogICAgInRpdG9sbyI6IkVJQ01BIDIwMjEsIEJlbmVsbGkgXCJzZm9ybmFcIiBsZSBtb3RvIHBp+SBhdHRlc2UiLAogICAgImlkIjoiMTQ2OTc1IiwKICAgICJpbW1hZ2luZSI6ImJlbmVsbGlfMi5qcGciLAogICAgImRhdGEiOiIyNy8xMS8yMDIxIgogICAgfQogICAgXSwKICAgICJDb3VudCI6NCwiU2Nhbm5lZENvdW50Ijo0fQo=";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let allart = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    let ids = allart.Items.map(item => item.id).join('<br/>');
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = ids;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<div id="id"></div>
```